# Proper way to document an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API action that returns a binary document with Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm trying to document an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API action that returns a binary document from a system based on an id. The type of the returned document all depends on the document that is referenced by the id. In other words, the document may be a `.pdf`, `.txt` or a `.docx` file.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDocument([Required] int documentId)
{
   result = _repo.GetDocument(documentId); 
   
   if (result == null)
      return NotFound();

   return File(Convert.FromBase64String(result.Data), result.MimeType, result.FileName)
}
```

What is the proper way to document such a method with Swagger?

- show the response type is string with media type of `application/octet-stream`?
- show the response type is byte[] with media type of `application/octet-stream`?
- something else?

I'm using Swashbuckle to generate the Swagger definition so I'm looking for something that can be implemented via attributes rather than manually defining a swagger definition file.

Comment: 1) What I'm returning is not base64 -- its a FileContentResult that was created from byte[].  2) The endpoint will return whatever mime-type the file has -- there's no way to know what that is until the endpoint is actually called -- swagger deals with documentation prior to any calls being made.  IOW, how can you document actual file formats when you don't know what is going to be returned.

Comment: i think you need to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271153/return-a-file-stream-using-swashbuckle